# Converting a vector to input of a matrix/array

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

Say one has

```
input=c(1,2)
mat=matrix(1:9,ncol=3)
```

how does one convert the input vector into a form that allows one to call

```
mat[input]
```

and receive the mat[1,2] element of the matrix? I ask because I want to edit elements of an array of length n.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short Answer:

```
mat[t(input)]
```

#### Explanation:

Chambers' book *Software for Data Analysis* lists 4 ways to subset (i.e., extract elements of) a matrix.  Method #2 is the answer to the question posted above.  I'll post each of Chambers' 4 ways with a short example.  For the examples, we'll use the matrix `m` and we'll extract elements in the (4,1) and (6,2) positions, which have values 104 and 116, respectively.

```
m <- matrix(101:120, ncol=2)
```

**1.** Separately index the columns and rows:

```
m[4,1]
m[6,2]
```

**2.** Use a 2-column matrix as a single index argument

```
k <- rbind(c(4,1), c(6,2))
m[k]
```

**3.** Use logical expressions

```
m[1:10 == 4, 1:2 == 1]
m[1:10 == 6, 1:2 == 2]
#or
m[1:20 %in% c(4,16)]
```

**4.** Use vector subsetting because a matrix is just a vector wrapped columnwise

```
m[c(4,16)]
```

---

Here's a screenshot of Chambers' book pages 201--202:

[image: Chambers Book pages 201-202]

Comment: Thanks for the resource- And this approach works for my array problem also.